# Transpose and crop RasterBrick R

Tags: r, crop, raster, transpose

**A)** How to transpose a rasterbrick containing many layers?

```
prr <- brick('dat.nc4',transpose=T)#transpose=T does not transpose

> proj4string(prr) <-crs("+proj=longlat +datum=NAD83 +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0")
NOTE: rgdal::checkCRSArgs: no proj_defs.dat in PROJ.4 shared files

> prr
class       : RasterBrick
dimensions  : 3600, 1800, 6480000, 732  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 0.1, 0.1  (x, y)
extent      : -90, 90, -180, 180  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=NAD83 +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0
data source : /data/Run.nc4
names       : X20150401, X20150401.25, X20150401.5, X20150401.75, X20150402, X20150402.25, X20150402.5, X20150402.75, X20150403, X20150403.25, X20150403.5, X20150403.75, X20150404, X20150404.25, X20150404.5, ...
z-value     : 20150401, 20150930 (min, max)
varname     : precipitationCal
```

You can see from the file attributes that lat and lon are flipped.
Trying to transpose the rasterbrick yields the following error:

```
A=t(pr)

    Error in matrix(unlist(ini), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE) :
      'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'
    In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

How can I `transpose` all layers in `dat.nc4`?

```
#########################################################
```

**B)**

I also got the same error trying to crop:

```
cr <- crop(dat, extent(-141.01807 , -52.61941, 41.68144, 60), snap="out")
NOTE: rgdal::checkCRSArgs: no proj_defs.dat in PROJ.4 shared files
Error in matrix(unlist(ini), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE) :
  'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'
```

The brick and crop functions work great if I read just one layer using `prr <- raster('dat.nc4',transpose=T)`

Thanks for your thoughts on this.

AT.

The files I am analysing can be downloaded here [http://disc.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/SSW/#keywords=GPM_3IMERGHH 03](http://disc.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/SSW/#keywords=GPM_3IMERGHH%2003)

Comment: No idea as to why the transpose argument is being ignored but , have you tried "rotate" or "flip" on the resulting brick object.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans  I tried `flip` to no avail. Even the `crop` function does not work on the `rasterbrick`.

Comment: Hi @code123, have you found a solution to solve the "crop" problem?

Comment: @just_rookie Yes I found a solution already.

Comment: Hi @code123, would you mind sharing the solution for cropping a rasterbrick?